# How to get a substring of variable size for each row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I have a MySQL table with **just** a single text type column with lots of information in the same format, starting with a string like this:

```
Field1 : 1234
Field2 : Something
```

The column always starts with **Field1** and **Field2**, but the values after each Field are different for each record.

What I need is to get the just the values of what's after **Field1** and **Field2** (in this case **1234** and **Something**) on a Query, the value after **Field1** is easy because it's always 4 characters long, but the problem is the one after **Field2** because it's size varies for each record, what I have so far is this:

```
SELECT SELECT substring(substring_index(COLUMN,'Field1 : ',-1),1,4) as Field1_value
FROM table
```

I know after **Field2**'s value there's a line break, so I'll think of considering the **\n** character to delimit the value I need.

How do I get this substring of variable size for each row?

P.S. Yes the data is horribly structured, I'm not able to change it...

Comment: You do realise that your data is horribly structured, don't you?

Comment: I do indeed, that's the way it is, and unfortunately I'm not able to change it.

Comment: Any reason you want to do the string manipulation in the query rather then where your return this data into?

Comment: It's part of a really restrictive system, so that's not an option in this case (if it was my first option would be using Perl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, finally I got it (thanks for your contributions everybody), this is the final resulting Query:

```
select substring(subcolumn, 9,5) as Field1, 
    substring(subcolumn,  24) as Field2 
    from (        
        select substring(COLUMN, 1, locate('\n',COLUMN,15)) as subcolumn
        from table
) as X
```

Knowing the size of the strings "Field1 : " and "Field2 : ", this isolates those 2 strings and their following values from the rest of column's text, and then I use a substring (knowing that the value after Field1 is always 4 characters long helps), and the 15 in the substring is to ensure I look not for the second line break.

Comment: The `substring(COLUMN, 1, locate('\n',COLUMN,15))` can be simplified to `SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLUMN, '\n', 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Supply a dynamic value as the last parameter of substring():

```
select 
   substring(your_column,
              length('FieldX : ')+1,
              length(your_column) - length('FieldX : ') + 1) as FieldX
from your_table;
```

This will work for any single-digit X in FieldX.

Comment: That's not getting what I expected in the case of Field2, the size of the string **FieldX :** is always the same, the problem is I don't know what's coming **after** Field2 : (nor it's lenght)

Comment: The above query doesn't need to know what's coming after "Field2 : ".  Rather, it subtracts the length of "Field 2 : " from the length of the field in each individual record. It does this dynamically so you don't need to know what's coming after "Field 2 : ". Maybe I misunderstood your question? Let me know what happens when you run the query.

Comment: Sorry yeah I guess the issue here is I didn't explain myself very well, the result I want is whatever is coming after "Field2 : "

Comment: Please run the above query and let me know if it doesn't give you what you need.

Comment: It doesn't, I'm using "Field2 : ", and it shows 2 characters after Field1, then everything else on COLUMN

Comment: I think you might have have used regular single-quotes around `COLUMN` instead of back-ticks as in the above.  You probably don't need backticks because your actual column name probably isn't COLUMN. In other words change the above to 
   select substring(your_column,
              length('FieldX : ')+1,
              length(your_column) - length('FieldX : ') + 1) as FieldX
from your_table; I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, you're right about the column name, and I tried just like your solution shows, and the result I get is everything at all after "Field1 : " (regardless of the value of X)

Answer (score 1):

If the format of the columns is always the same `FieldX :` then:

```
SELECT 
     SUBSTRING(COLUMN, LOCATE(':', COLUMN)+2) as FieldValue
FROM table;
```

should give you what you need.

**ADDED BASED ON CLARIFIED DATA**

If you actually have data separated from `Field2` value by `\n` then your query can become:

```
SELECT
     SUBSTRING(COLUMN, LOCATE('Field1 : ', COLUMN)+9, 4) as Field1
     SUBSTRING(COLUMN, LOCATE('Field2 : ', COLUMN)+9, LOCATE(CHAR(10), COLUMN) - LOCATE('Field2 : ', COLUMN)+9) as Field2,
     SUBSTRING(COLUMN, LOCATE(CHAR(10), COLUMN)+1) as RestOfData
FROM table;
```

Something still tells me that whatever you return this data into should be able to parse it better.

Comment: You're missing the column name in LOCATE(), and this outputs to something like: 
ield1 : 1234
Field2 : Somethin<everything else>

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest is:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( Column, 10 ) AS Field1_value
FROM table
```

Comment: This returns everything at all after "Field1 : "

Comment: @darkajax: That's what you want, isn't it?

Comment: Well, not exactly, what I wanted is whatever is between **Field1** and **Field2** and whatever is between **Field2** and the next part of the column (before a line break)

Comment: I see your answer now. You had all this text in **one** field. This was not obvious at all from the description...

Comment: And I guess you have another line-break after `1234` and before `Field2 :`

Comment: That's right, that's why I said at the beginning: "single text type column", sorry for the ambiguity...

Comment: OK. I think what confused me was the *"The column always starts with Field1 and Field2"*